# I can't install eventlet/gevent/greenlet

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, gevent, eventlet

I'm using Flask-SocketIO for a project of mine, and it's causing some issues, i.e. the client isn't able to connect to the server. I figured this may be due to it using the flask default development server, so I tried to install `eventlet`, but it didn't work. I got this error:

```
  Running setup.py install for greenlet ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/arnu515/Documents/code/videochat/temp/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/62/291hqhv517j2x50bfw65mj8r0000gn/T/pip-install-kilo4pkb/greenlet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/62/291hqhv517j2x50bfw65mj8r0000gn/T/pip-install-kilo4pkb/greenlet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/62/291hqhv517j2x50bfw65mj8r0000gn/T/pip-record-bl7qcak2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/arnu515/Documents/code/videochat/temp/venv/include/site/python3.8/greenlet
         cwd: /private/var/folders/62/291hqhv517j2x50bfw65mj8r0000gn/T/pip-install-kilo4pkb/greenlet/
    Complete output (112 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'greenlet' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
    xcrun -sdk macosx clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -I/Users/arnu515/Documents/code/videochat/temp/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c greenlet.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/greenlet.o
    In file included from greenlet.c:5:
    In file included from ./greenlet.h:8:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:63:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
    #error Unsupported architecture
     ^
    In file included from greenlet.c:5:
    In file included from ./greenlet.h:8:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:64:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/limits.h:8:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    In file included from greenlet.c:5:
    In file included from ./greenlet.h:8:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    In file included from greenlet.c:5:
    In file included from ./greenlet.h:8:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
    typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
            ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
    typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
            ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
    typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
            ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
    typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
            ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    In file included from greenlet.c:5:
    In file included from ./greenlet.h:8:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    In file included from greenlet.c:5:
    In file included from ./greenlet.h:8:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    20 errors generated.
    error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/arnu515/Documents/code/videochat/temp/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/62/291hqhv517j2x50bfw65mj8r0000gn/T/pip-install-kilo4pkb/greenlet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/62/291hqhv517j2x50bfw65mj8r0000gn/T/pip-install-kilo4pkb/greenlet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/62/291hqhv517j2x50bfw65mj8r0000gn/T/pip-record-bl7qcak2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/arnu515/Documents/code/videochat/temp/venv/include/site/python3.8/greenlet Check the logs for full command output.
```

Same thing happens with gevent. Can you please help me fix this?

FYI - OS: MacOS, Python: 3.8.9

Comment: I managed to fix the problem with flask-socketio by downgrading to socketio 2 on the client, and as for eventlet, @Rivers answer works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is described here (and there are solutions to this problem): https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/issues/3770

And here too: https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet/issues/181

**In short:**

It's a problem with the Python version on macOS, especially the Python version that ships with Xcode.
As you can see in the line beginning with `xcrun -sdk macosx`, it's trying to build an arm64 slice, so it raises the error `error architecture not supported`.

*These solutions worked for other users:*

**First solution:**

Upgrade to the latest version of Python : from brew, from python.org or from pyenv.

**Second solution:**

Perhaps you already have the latest version of Python, so you could do this:

```
brew link --overwrite python@3.8
```

**Third solution:**

Use conda:

Instal miniconda (https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/macos.html)

```
# Create the environment (here, named "myenv")
conda create --name myenv

# Activate the environment
conda activate myenv

# In this environment, install the Python packages you need
conda install -c conda-forge flask-socketio
# Etc.
```

And then run your code **from** this virtual environment

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked! Specifically, I used the second solution that you gave me. Many thanks